# Remove all capital word from beginning of sentence

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a set of sentences all starting with a name, like

> Humpty Dumpty fell down.
>   Mini Miny Moe went to Meadville, Mississippi.
>   Little Piglet is a squealer.

How can I easily pull the name out from the sentences?

The regex `/([A-Z])\w+/g` will give me all words with an uppercase, but I don't want a hit on `Meadville` and `Mississippi`.

So for the given examples, I would want the following output:

```
"Humpty Dumpty", " fell down."  
"Mini Miny Moe", " went to Meadville, Mississippi."  
"Little Piglet", " is a squealer."
```

I need the name as one string and the rest as another string.  If it's an array of two strings or an object with two properties - I don't care, as long as I have them separated.

Suggestions?

Comment: what output you exptect?

Comment: What if the line starts with `Mississippi`...?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub I think he just means he doesn't want those capitalized words that come later in the sentence.

Comment: Name detection can be very tricky as some name components may contain a period in it.

Comment: And I thing @ThomasAyoub just saw a good opportunity to mess with me ;-)

Comment: What about `Yesterday Mr Pigglet fell down` ?

Comment: True, @ThomasAyoub. Shouldn't all proper English sentences start with a capital letter?

Comment: He clearly told us "...all starting with a name..."

Comment: Just for the record [falsehoods programmers believe about names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: Luckily, developers some times get small specific tasks to tackle, where there are given strict limitations to the problem at hand. No need to try over-complicate things. I had a hard time making my regex do what I wanted, and wanted some help. My experience is that it is much easier to get an answer if I construct a easy problem with examples, but I guess choosing to use the 'name' as part of it made it hard for some. Anyway, @Roberto did a great job of answering the question, so thank you Roberto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it

```
/^([A-Z][a-z]* )+/
```

it will match:

```
Humpty Dumpty fell down. --> Humpty Dumpty
Mini Miny Moe went to Meadville, Mississippi. --> Mini Miny Moe
Little Piglet is a squealer. --> Little Piglet
```

**EDIT**

To capture like the example you put:

```
/^((?:[A-Z][a-z]* )+)(.*)/
```

it will give you *almost* what you want, shouldn't be hard remove trailing space or add spaces where you need them:

```
Humpty Dumpty fell down. --> "Humpty Dumpty ", "fell down."
Mini Miny Moe went to Meadville, Mississippi. --> "Mini Miny Moe ", "went to Meadville, Mississippi."
Little Piglet is a squealer. --> "Little Piglet ", "is a squealer."
```

**EDIT 2:**

Following advice in comment, so you don't need to deal with adding/removing spaces after geting the groups:

```
/^([A-Z][a-z]*(?:\s+[A-Z][a-z]*)*)(.*)/
```

And if you need *René Descartes* or *Shane Baker-Oropeza* as names:

```
/^([A-ZÁÉÍÓÚ][a-záéíóú]*(?:(?:\s|-)+[A-ZÁÉÍÓÚ][a-záéíóú]*)*)(.*)/
```

Comment: Nice catch, just be aware that `Jean-Paul` or `René` may cross your regex... You've got my upvote anyway

Comment: I was just about to make a comment on the miss-placed space. :-)

Comment: The `\w` character class - will it match the 'strange' letters? (Like øøå as well) But it might not be possible to enforce the uppercase letter that way? I see some refers to a '`[:upper:]`-posix' but I guess it's not supported in JavaScript..

Answer (score 0):

You will need to expand your business rule. Just looking for a space between words that begin with a capital letter will allow cities like Silver Spring, MD to slip through. Every town that begins with "New " will also slip through.

I am not sure how you will do this.

Also, if you compare against a city data table, you will drop people names that match city names. For instance, ay you have a native American doctor named Silver Spring. If he included his title, ", MD", it matches exactly.

Comment: I don't need to expand my business rule, since the business rule is already well defined. There will be names in the beginning, and nothing else. If there are valid sentences where the first two 'terms' of is first a name and then a city, like 'Humpty Dumpty London...', it's simply not part of this problem domain.